# Using Dataset with TimeObjects in EventSeries

Tags: dataset, date-and-time, time-series

I'm new to *Mathematica*, and while this is potentially quite easy, I'm having difficulty using `TimeObject`s in the `EventSeries` function.
After pulling out a column from an original dataset which had a series of time values, I then applied `Count` as `Count @ Original` which gave me a table akin to:

```
Dataset[<|
    DateObject[{2016, 1, 1}, TimeObject[{12, 00, 0.}, TimeZone -> 10.],
        TimeZone -> 10.] -> 26,
    DateObject[{2016, 1, 1}, TimeObject[{01, 00, 0.}, TimeZone -> 10.],
        TimeZone -> 10.] -> 364, 
    DateObject[{2016, 1, 1}, TimeObject[{02, 00, 0.}, TimeZone -> 10.], 
        TimeZone -> 10.] -> 16|>]
```

My question is 2-fold.

1) How do I pass that dataset to the `EventSeries` function, to be able to do a `TimeSeries`-esque plot? I'm finding it particularly difficult to find anything that references passing `TimeObject`s, hence the question.

2) Given that I am new to *Mathematica*, my second question is more conceptually, about the easiest way to pass multiple lists (or as I would previously call them, columns of a `Dataset`) to a function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can operate upon data contained within dataset by applying query operators.  Assume that the dataset described in the question has been assigned to the variable `ds`.  Then, for example, we can convert the embedded association into an event series by applying the `EventSeries` operator:

```
ds[EventSeries]
```

[image: dataset EventSeries screenshot]

Alternatively, we could produce a plot by composing the `EventSeries` and `DateListPlot` operators:

```
ds[EventSeries /* DateListPlot]
```

[image: dataset DateListPlot screenshot]

It is likely that these operators can be applied directly to your original dataset.  Let's consider the following dataset:

```
ds2 = Query[Dataset, DateObject] @
  {{2016, 1, 1}, {2016, 1, 1}, {2017, 1, 1}, {2017, 1, 1}, {2017, 1, 1}, {2018, 1, 1}};
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

As in the question, we could use `Counts @ ds2` to get the number of occurrences of each date as an association (contained in a dataset).  But instead, let's express this operation in query form:

```
ds2[Counts]
```

[image: <code>Counts</code> screenshot]

The advantage of using query operator syntax is that we can now compose it with our other query operators to produce the plot directly from the source dataset:

```
ds2[Counts /* EventSeries /* DateListPlot]
```

[image: <code>Counts</code> plot screenshot]

Dataset query syntax is quite elaborate.  It is described in detail by the [Dataset](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) and [Query](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) documentation.

**Applying a Function to Multiple Columns**

As for the second question, a simple way to apply a function to multiple columns is to use named slot syntax (e.g. `#columnName`).  For example, consider this dataset:

```
ds3 = Query[Dataset, AssociationThread[{"a", "b", "c"} -> #]&] @ RandomInteger[10, {5, 3}]
```

[image: three-column dataset screenshot]

We can add together the columns *a* and *c* by means of the query operator `#a + #c&`:

```
ds3[All, #a + #c &]
```

[image: column sum screenshot]

Alternatively, we could produce a bar chart of those sums:

```
ds3[BarChart, #a + #c &]
```

[image: bar chart screenshot]

Comment: The number of ways to apply functions to arbitrary components of a dataset (columns or otherwise) is endless.  It might make sense to ask separate, more focused, questions on this topic (or review some of the other questions under the [tag:dataset] or [tag:query] tags).

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate that there are a seemingly endless way to apply functions, but I was looking for something a little more general that I can try to apply to each problem before I run into trouble.The extra detail about how to use functions to work with the new dataset was super helpful.

Answer (score 4):

[`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) has only been around since version 10.0, and not all functions support it as yet.  However, [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) has much broader support and is what `Dataset` is based on.  You can use [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) to convert the `Dataset` into an `Association`.  [`EventSeries`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EventSeries.html) can work with associations.

With `ds` as the `Dataset` in the above post, then

```
EventSeries[Normal@ds]

(* EventSeries[Time: 31 Dec 2015 12:00:00 to 31 Dec 2015 23:00:00   Data points: 3] *)
```

Hope this helps.